# Is there a way to programmatically interact with google docs?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to programmatically interact with google docs? I would like to be able to program actions like highlighting text, changing font size/color/type, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I just added a answer. If you need further help, please [edit] or post a new question but first including a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. This could be done by using Google Apps Script and/or the Google Documents API.